# XQuery Average of child element based on different child element

Tags: database, xquery, saxon

So I've been having some trouble getting the avg function to work how I want in XQuery. I have a XML file of students who have a GPA and a Classification (Freshmen, Sophomore, Junior, Senior). I want to find the average GPA's for each classification. I start by getting distinct classifications. I then get a list of all students and select average GPA when the student classification = the distinct classification. This returns 4 average GPA's (which I want) but they are all the same. I've been at this small problem for hours and want to be able to move forward with my assignment but this is giving me too much trouble. Code is as follows:

```
<T> {
   for $dc in distinct-values(doc("ComS363/UniversityDatasets/Student.xml")/Students/Student/Classification)
   let $student := doc("ComS363/UniversityDatasets/Student.xml")/Students/Student
   let $aveGPA := avg($student/GPA)
   where $student/Classification = $dc
   return
   <Classification>{$aveGPA}</Classification>
} </T>;
```

And my Student table is set up as follows:

```
<Students>
  <Student>
    <StudentID>118784412</StudentID>
    <Classification>Sophomore</Classification>
    <GPA>3.19</GPA>
    <MentorID>201586985</MentorID>
    <CreditHours>39</CreditHours>
  </Student>
.
.
.
.
</Students>
```

So do you guys have any idea why I am not getting unique average GPA's for classification here?
Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `where` clause filters the results that are returned, not the preceding variable bindings. Because of this, `avg($student/GPA)` will always evaluate to the average GPA of all students.

Instead, combine the filtering step with the variable binding:

```
let $aveGPA := avg($student[Classification = $dc]/GPA)
```

For better readability, you could apply the predicate condition to the `$student` variable:

```
let $student := doc("ComS363/UniversityDatasets/Student.xml")/Students/Student[Classification = $dc]
let $aveGPA := avg($student/GPA)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That makes sense. I am on the road right now but once I am home I'll try it out.